# How i can change the android code in order to link to my json

Tags: android, json

I have a android project in which i should link to server with json and then, recieved information is shown by custom list view.

this code works by the type of json shown in FIGURE 1.but, the form of json which i use is something like what shown in FIGURE 2.

in the other world, the json which i used doesn't have ("feed":).

now the question is how i can change the code in order to link to my json.

Thanks.

```
MainActivity.java
package info.androidhive.listviewfeed;

import info.androidhive.listviewfeed.adapter.FeedListAdapter;
import info.androidhive.listviewfeed.app.AppController;
import info.androidhive.listviewfeed.data.FeedItem;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.android.volley.Cache;
import com.android.volley.Cache.Entry;
import com.android.volley.Request.Method;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private ListView listView;
    private FeedListAdapter listAdapter;
    private List<FeedItem> feedItems;
    private String URL_FEED = "http://api.androidhive.info/feed/feed.json";

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        feedItems = new ArrayList<FeedItem>();

        listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(this, feedItems);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        // These two lines not needed,
        // just to get the look of facebook (changing background color & hiding the icon)
        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#3b5998")));
        getActionBar().setIcon(
                   new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));

        // We first check for cached request
        Cache cache = AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache();
        Entry entry = cache.get(URL_FEED);
        if (entry != null) {
            // fetch the data from cache
            try {
                String data = new String(entry.data, "UTF-8");
                try {
                    parseJsonFeed(new JSONObject(data));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            // making fresh volley request and getting json
            JsonObjectRequest jsonReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
                    URL_FEED, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());
                            if (response != null) {
                                parseJsonFeed(response);
                            }
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        }
                    });

            // Adding request to volley request queue
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Parsing json reponse and passing the data to feed view list adapter
     * */
    private void parseJsonFeed(JSONObject response) {
        try {
            JSONArray feedArray = response.getJSONArray("feed");

            for (int i = 0; i < feedArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject feedObj = (JSONObject) feedArray.get(i);

                FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
                item.setId(feedObj.getInt("id"));
                item.setName(feedObj.getString("name"));

                // Image might be null sometimes
                String image = feedObj.isNull("image") ? null : feedObj
                        .getString("image");
                item.setImge(image);
                item.setStatus(feedObj.getString("status"));
                item.setProfilePic(feedObj.getString("profilePic"));
                item.setTimeStamp(feedObj.getString("timeStamp"));

                // url might be null sometimes
                String feedUrl = feedObj.isNull("url") ? null : feedObj
                        .getString("url");
                item.setUrl(feedUrl);

                feedItems.add(item);
            }

            // notify data changes to list adapater
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

---

FIGURE 1:

```
  {
    "feed": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "National Geographic Channel",
            "image": "http://api.androidhive.info/feed/img/cosmos.jpg",
            "status": "\"Science is a beautiful and emotional human endeavor,\" says Brannon Braga, executive producer and director. \"And Cosmos is all about making science an experience.\"",
            "profilePic": "http://api.androidhive.info/feed/img/nat.jpg",
            "timeStamp": "1403375851930",
            "url": null
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "TIME",
            "image": "http://api.androidhive.info/feed/img/time_best.jpg",
            "status": "30 years of Cirque du Soleil's best photos",
            "profilePic": "http://api.androidhive.info/feed/img/time.png",
            "timeStamp": "1403375851930",
            "url": "http://ti.me/1qW8MLB"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Discovery",
            "image": "http://api.androidhive.info/feed/img/discovery_mos.jpg",
            "status": "A team of Austrian scientists has developed a laser system that causes fruit flies to dance.",
            "profilePic": "http://api.androidhive.info/feed/img/discovery.jpg",
            "timeStamp": "1403375851930",
            "url": "http://dsc.tv/xmMxD"
        }
    ]
}
```

---

FIGURE 2:

```
       [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "National Geographic Channel",
                "image": "http://api.androidhive.info/feed/img/cosmos.jpg",
                "status": "\"Science is a beautiful and emotional human endeavor,\" says Brannon Braga, executive producer and director. \"And Cosmos is all about making science an experience.\"",
                "profilePic": "http://api.androidhive.info/feed/img/nat.jpg",
                "timeStamp": "1403375851930",
                "url": null
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "TIME",
                "image": "http://api.androidhive.info/feed/img/time_best.jpg",
                "status": "30 years of Cirque du Soleil's best photos",
                "profilePic": "http://api.androidhive.info/feed/img/time.png",
                "timeStamp": "1403375851930",
                "url": "http://ti.me/1qW8MLB"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Discovery",
                "image": "http://api.androidhive.info/feed/img/discovery_mos.jpg",
                "status": "A team of Austrian scientists has developed a laser system that causes fruit flies to dance.",
                "profilePic": "http://api.androidhive.info/feed/img/discovery.jpg",
                "timeStamp": "1403375851930",
                "url": "http://dsc.tv/xmMxD"
            }
        ]
```

Comment: Your JSON structure is a `JSONArray`, so change `onResponse` and any related methods to expect a `JSONArray` back from the server

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private ListView listView;
private FeedListAdapter listAdapter;
private List<FeedItem> feedItems;
private String URL_FEED = "http://api.androidhive.info/feed/feed.json";

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    feedItems = new ArrayList<FeedItem>();

    listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(this, feedItems);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    // These two lines not needed,
    // just to get the look of facebook (changing background color & hiding the icon)
    getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#3b5998")));
    getActionBar().setIcon(
               new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));

    // We first check for cached request
    Cache cache = AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache();
    Entry entry = cache.get(URL_FEED);
    if (entry != null) {
        // fetch the data from cache
        try {
            String data = new String(entry.data, "UTF-8");
            try {
                parseJsonFeed(new JSONArray(data));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } else {
        // making fresh volley request and getting json
        JsonArrayRequest jsonReq = new JsonArrayRequest(Method.GET,
                URL_FEED, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());
                        if (response != null) {
                            parseJsonFeed(response);
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    }
                });

        // Adding request to volley request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);
    }

}

/**
 * Parsing json reponse and passing the data to feed view list adapter
 * */
private void parseJsonFeed(JSONArray feedArray) {
    try {

        for (int i = 0; i < feedArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject feedObj = (JSONObject) feedArray.get(i);

            FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
            item.setId(feedObj.getInt("id"));
            item.setName(feedObj.getString("name"));

            // Image might be null sometimes
            String image = feedObj.isNull("image") ? null : feedObj
                    .getString("image");
            item.setImge(image);
            item.setStatus(feedObj.getString("status"));
            item.setProfilePic(feedObj.getString("profilePic"));
            item.setTimeStamp(feedObj.getString("timeStamp"));

            // url might be null sometimes
            String feedUrl = feedObj.isNull("url") ? null : feedObj
                    .getString("url");
            item.setUrl(feedUrl);

            feedItems.add(item);
        }

        // notify data changes to list adapater
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: Have you check the answer if yes and its working so please accept the answer